# Indoor map should accessible to authenticated user only

Tags: android, google-maps, authentication, google-indoor-maps

Is it possible to upload floor Map/Indoor Map and it will be accessible to authenticated or selected users only in Google Cloud?

OR if I want to do same then what SDK or example I should use.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

For authenticating the users you need to set your project with [OAuth protocol.](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2)

To begin, obtain OAuth 2.0 client credentials from the Google Developers Console. Then your client application requests an access token from the Google Authorization Server, extracts a token from the response, and sends the token to the Google API that you want to access. A single access token can grant varying degrees of access to multiple APIs. A variable parameter called scope controls the set of resources and operations that an access token permits.

To work with [indoor maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map#indoor_maps) in the API you can visit this page.